# How to indicate a specific JSON path?

Tags: json, jasper-reports

This is my test data:

```
{
  "errorCode": null,
  "errorMessage": null,
  "responseItems": [
    {
      "errorCode": null,
      "errorMessage": null,
      "personId": "FCC2",
      "personCode": "SUNEETHA",
      "personFirstName": "suneetha",
      "personLastName": "Durgam",
      "office": "London",
      "officeCode": "L",
      "department": "Product",
      "departmentCode": "PR",
      "subDepartment": "QA",
      "subDepartmentCode": "QA",
      "timeOffStaffSummaryDTO": [
        {
          "officeCode": null,
          "startMonthYear": null,
          "endMonthYear": null,
          "personId": null,
          "alphaId": null,
          "continent": null,
          "allowancesIntotal": 20,
          "allowancesUsed": 0,
          "allowancesSubmitted": 0,
          "allowancesApproved": 0,
          "allowancesRemaining": 20,
          "timeOffType": {
            "id": 4001,
            "continent": "EU",
            "alphaId": "9J",
            "code": "PTO",
            "description": "Personal Time Offdd",
            "account": "MADMIN",
            "colourCode": "#CCCCCC",
            "approvalRequired": true,
            "commentRequired": false,
            "paid": true
          },
          "timeOffTypeWithoutAllowance": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to get to the Timeoff type description using this path:

```
$.responseItems[0].timeOffStaffSummaryDTO[0].timeOffType.description
```

Now, this works with any json path tester I have tried online, but the template won't display this value in the page header band.

In the repeating Detail band, I am also trying to display this:

```
$.responseItems.timeOffStaffSummaryDTO[0].timeOffTypeWithoutAllowance
```

Tried it without the $ sign or the first dot, no difference, it always displays null. I have also tried it in the field description or as a value for property "net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression".

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing how to declare your fields when using json, I will show you an example considering your json.

If the base path for your datasource (queryString, the report will iterate the detail band on these items) is `responseItems`

```
<queryString language="JSON">
    <![CDATA[responseItems]]>
</queryString>
```

To access `personCode` you will define a field as

```
<field name="personCode" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[personCode]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

The **fieldDescription** is the path in your json, hence to access `timeOffStaffSummaryDTO[0].timeOffType.description` you need to declare a field

```
<field name="timeOffStaffSummaryDTOTimeOffTypeDescription" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[timeOffStaffSummaryDTO[0].timeOffType.description]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

> The name can be whatever you like, the class is the corresponding java
>   class of the value and the `fieldDescription` needs to be the path relative to your
>   datasource (queryString).

**Full example**

Full example with `timeOffStaffSummaryDTO[0].timeOffType.description` in both header (bold) and in detail band

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="jsonTest" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="afa1e750-acfe-4d43-92ff-76e139d34dac">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="JsonTest"/>
    <queryString language="JSON">
        <![CDATA[responseItems]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="personCode" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[personCode]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="timeOffStaffSummaryDTOTimeOffTypeDescription" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[timeOffStaffSummaryDTO[0].timeOffType.description]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="260" height="30" uuid="449b7c85-a952-4205-9595-de2647d563ed"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{timeOffStaffSummaryDTOTimeOffTypeDescription}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="32" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="180" height="30" uuid="832d525e-b932-4563-9f00-c4e3fc671061"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{personCode}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="180" y="0" width="260" height="30" uuid="528a9d25-2329-4f1f-b0be-21d1b6b8a5a0"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{timeOffStaffSummaryDTOTimeOffTypeDescription}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

**Output**

[image: result]

Comment: Many, many thanks - especially for taking the time to show code and the output! My query definition was correct but my field definition was off - I needed to get rid of the .responseItems bit. Very new to using JSONPath, had only dealt with xml data till now.